# Expose a constant variable from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header

I have to do a bitwise operation that is for some reason only possible in swift so I am looking to initialize some constants with Objective-C to be used within my application.

I am not that great with objective-c yet so the only way I knew how to do this was to create a class and give it a method that returns the value but I figure that there is a more efficient value.

There must be a more succinct way to achieve this. Currently I am doing the following:

Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <simd/simd.h>
#import <MetalKit/MetalKit.h>
#import <Metal/Metal.h>

@interface Bridge:NSObject

 @property NSString *url;

 - (MTLTextureUsage)readAndWrite;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "MPS-Bridging-Header.h"

@implementation Bridge

- (MTLTextureUsage)readAndWrite {
    return MTLTextureUsageShaderRead | MTLTextureUsageRenderTarget | MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite;
}

@end
```

Swift Usage:

```
let bridge = Bridge()
Texture.usage = bridge.readAndWrite()
```

It would be great if this could be simplified to like
`MTLTexReadAndWrite` as if it were a constant or perhaps have it so that I can do `Bridge().readAndWrite()` so it is all on one line?

Comment: Why do you need objective-c?

Comment: Pretty much anything in Swift can be done in ObjectiveC and vice versa.  What is it you think needs to be done in Swift (or ObjectiveC)?

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/159251). Does the value need to be read from _both_ Swift _and_ ObjC? Or only from one or the other? If only one, which? What does "for some reason only possible in swift" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to expose this to Swift, I'd define a class property:

```
//  Bridge.h

@import Foundation;
@import Metal;

@interface Bridge : NSObject

@property (class, nonatomic, readonly) MTLTextureUsage readAndWrite;

@end
```

And

```
//  Bridge.m

#import "Bridge.h"

@implementation Bridge

+ (MTLTextureUsage)readAndWrite {
    return MTLTextureUsageShaderRead | MTLTextureUsageRenderTarget | MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite;
}

@end
```

And you could then use it like so:

```
let readAndWrite = Bridge.readAndWrite
```

But I wonder why you don't just define this constant in Swift:

```
let readAndWrite: MTLTextureUsage = [.shaderRead, .renderTarget, .shaderWrite]
```

If you need the same constant in both Objective-C and Swift, use the above bridging pattern, but if you only need it in Swift, then I'd just define it there and eliminate `Bridge` altogether.

Comment: Sort of think you should move the "but I wonder why you don't" section to the top. I suspect the OP just ran into some little weird problem and went down a rabbit hole.

Comment: I suspect you're right, but I hate to presume. I am trying to adopt a charitable position of "the OP must have had a good reason to do what he/she did", until proven otherwise. Plus, just in case future readers come here looking for real "Expose a constant variable from Objective-C to Swift" questions, I want to answer the question of the title.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. :)

Comment: I really appreciate that you showed the Objective-c solution in addition to the proper swift solution I aught to be using. Thanks!